# RPC Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '

Tags: node.js, ethereum, truffle, metamask

I am trying to test my application with truffle and metamask but whenever I confirm the transaction from the metamask pop up i am getting this error on console

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"message":"header not found","stack":"Error: header not found\n    at BlockManager.number [as get] (C:\\Users\\malha\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\webpack:\\Ganache\\chains\\ethereum\\ethereum\\lib\\src\\data-managers\\block-manager.js:199:15)\n    at AccountManager.data [as getRaw] (C:\\Users\\malha\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\webpack:\\Ganache\\chains\\ethereum\\ethereum\\lib\\src\\data-managers\\account-manager.js:33:28)\n    at AccountManager.getNonce (C:\\Users\\malha\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\webpack:\\Ganache\\chains\\ethereum\\ethereum\\lib\\src\\data-managers\\account-manager.js:40:15)","code":-32700}}}'
```

[image]

And sometimes another error occurs which is

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error
```

I tried many solutions given such restarting truffle, ganache, reseting the metamask account but nothings seems to work.